# A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Line Number: 436

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-server-2017

**A Database Error Occurred**

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/ci3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 436

I am using SQL SERVER 2017.

Database settings:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'RYNPRB';

$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';

$db['default']['password'] = 'riyan12@';

$db['default']['database'] = 'sample1';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';

$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production');

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['DBsecond']['hostname'] = 'RYNPRB';

$db['DBsecond']['username'] = 'sa';

$db['DBsecond']['password'] = 'riyan12@';

$db['DBsecond']['database'] = 'sample2';

$db['DBsecond']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';

$db['DBsecond']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['DBsecond']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production');

$db['DBsecond']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['DBsecond']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['DBsecond']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['DBsecond']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['DBsecond']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add username should be root ans restart your server

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'RYNPRB';

$db['default']['username'] = 'root';

$db['default']['password'] = 'riyan12@';

$db['default']['database'] = 'sample1';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';

$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production');

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['DBsecond']['hostname'] = 'RYNPRB';

$db['DBsecond']['username'] = 'sa';

$db['DBsecond']['password'] = 'riyan12@';

$db['DBsecond']['database'] = 'sample2';

$db['DBsecond']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';

$db['DBsecond']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['DBsecond']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production');

$db['DBsecond']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['DBsecond']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['DBsecond']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['DBsecond']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['DBsecond']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['DBsecond']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```